# What kinds of tuples does Npgsql support?

Tags: npgsql

I get various results when trying to retrieve tuples using Npgsql (v. 3.1.7).

A tuple of integers seems to work okay:

```sql
SELECT (1, 2)
```

This returns an object array containing the integers 1 and 2.

But with other data types, I get varying types of failures:

---

```sql
SELECT (1, 'two')
```

With this, I get an NpgsqlException with the text `Unknown message code: 0`.

---

```sql
SELECT (1, 2, 'three')
```

Same thing, but this time, the unknown message code is `101`.  That's the ASCII value of `'e'`, and if I tack an `'f'` onto the end (`'threef'`), then the code is `102`.

---

```sql
SELECT (1, 2, 3, 'four')
```

This time I get an object array containing the integers 1, 2, 3, and 1718580594.  This last is 0x666F7572.  `0x66`, `0x6F`, `0x75`, and `0x72` are the ASCII values of `'f'`, `'o'`, `'u'`, and `'r'`.

---

```sql
SELECT ('one', 2)
```

This hangs and eventually times out.

---

At one point when using ExecuteReader (also reproducible when filling a data set), I got an NpgsqlException with an inner EndOfStreamException, but I can't find an easy repro to post for that one.

---

Are these just bugs in Npgsql, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are bugs in Npgsql - it's probable all these cases stem from one bug actually. Can you please open an issue for these on http://github.com/npgsql/npgsql?

For the record, in PostgreSQL parlance `SELECT (1, 2)` doesn't return an array, it returns a record. An array is a different data type that can be returned with `SELECT '{1, 2}'::INTEGER[]`.

Comment: Will do, thanks, Shay.  Yes, I understand the tuple/record versus array distinction in Postgres, but since my first test with `SELECT (1, 2)` returned an object array, I assumed that object arrays are the type Npgsql uses to represent PostgreSQL's tuples, which seems reasonable to me.

Comment: I will submit a pull request fixing this issue, just to notify Shay

Comment: The fix works for my test cases and for my actual use case.  Thanks, Shay and Sami!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a but in Npgsql source. I debugged through it and there is quite an interesting bug. Npgsql reads the tuple item types as *ints* but the type mapper expects *uints*. It also has an indexer for *objects* and this is where the code leads. This causes it to try to read everything as ints.

I will submit a patch to Npgsql but if you want to fix it yourself for some reason, just go to TypeHandlers\RecordHandler.cs, method Read(out object[] result) and fix this line (86 in current dev branch):

```
var typeOID = _readBuf.ReadUInt32();
```

In the current source it has `ReadInt32()` which causes this issue.

After I fixed this I could use `GetValue()` and get an object array with ints, texts etc however I wanted.

Comment: Well done, I just fixed it myself :) Am waiting for the actual issue to be opened and will commit this.